# Create an .inf script to open a batch file as administrator

Tags: batch-file, admin

I`ve been looking around the web for a tutorial on how to make .inf scripts so I can execute a batch file from it. The problem is that the batch script needs admin to run so i have to get that in some way. Here is my code:

```
:start
echo off
copy program.jar "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

The program needs admin to copy to the Starup folder.
Thnx.

Comment: Copying an actual program to the start menu is bad practice.  Copy the program/jar to an `%appdata%\program` folder and then put a shortcut in the startup directory.  See the related SO posts for tips on elevating your batch script to have Administrator privileges if you must copy to the all users start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for the All User's folder. Only Admins can install for all users.

The per user startup folder is at `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`